Distant objects in rendering are not rendering correctly
I'm making an animation in blender and I have a seen where a stick figure is shown high up in the air and I have placed a large mesh to show distant mountains so you wouldn't see the bottom of the sky box. When I rendered the animation the mountains have lost all of its detail and now a solid wavy shape.



is your "large mesh to show distant mountains" a 4-vertex plane with a image of mountains, or actually a complex mesh with "peaks and valleys"?  If the latter, then perhaps you need to adjust or add lighting to graze along the surface area.

it is a 4-vertex plane that is subdivided and then has a bumpy geometry group attached.

Some modifiers like subdivision have a different setting for render and viewport. Make sure all the settings are synced and that you didn't accidentally disable the modifier for the render.   Lastly, are you using the scene level 'simplify' option? That could also affect some modifiers like subdiv.

I applied the simple subdivide modifer and it got the mountains to render properly in the render. I solved my problem but possibly exposes a bug in blender. (How I set modifiers: Subdivide (simple) -> Bumpy Surface (geometry nodes) -> Subdivide (smooth) -> Depth Corrected Outlines (geometry nodes)

I'm pretty sure this is not a bug, but to be sure I would need to understand how your "bumpy surface (geometry nodes)" and "depth corrected outlines (geometry nodes)" works. Still you did not really answered if you had different resolutions for "Viewport" and Render. Because if so, it renders with the Render resolution, but when you apply the modifier it applies the Viewport resolution, so after applying it is of course the same for rendering, too. That's not a bug, that's a problem of the settings and probably a misunderstanding of how the modifier works.

I applied the simple subdision modifier and the works in the render but I'm pretty sure my issue is a bug.

I'm pretty sure it is not, it is an incorrect Render setting in the Subdivision Surface modifier.
